# Is there a single word that refers to the length of either triangle's leg over the hypotenuse?

Tags: terminology

I don't mean arccos and arcsin, I mean a single word that would refer to both of them. Like, if I divide the length of either leg by the hypotenuse, is there a word that indicates the meaning of that number? Or maybe in terms of vector components and the magnitude?

Comment: Is "trigonometric function" what you are looking for?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that could also mean arctan. I'm talking about arccos or arcsin, but a single word that would mean those, like "hyp-scaled" or something.

Comment: "sinusoidal function" usually only refers to cosine or sine (or translates/modifications thereof), so maybe "inverse sinusoidal function". Otherwise I don't know and would like to find out the answer as well, hence why I upvoted.

Comment: Your comment of "hypotenuse scaled" makes me thinks perhaps "normalized" is the answer you seek.  If you have a vector, it has a vertical component and a horizontal component.  But sometimes you care more about the direction than the length.  So you divide by the "norm" which is essentially the length, and you have a unit vector left behind.

Comment: What's this business of "arc" something? Do you mean a common name for sin and cos?

Comment: One common definition of sin and cos is to consider a system of coordinates and a circle of radius 1 centered at the origin. Represent angles as points on the circle; then the "x" coordinate is the cosine and the "y" coordinate is the sine. In this arrangement, "x" and "y" have a collective name as the "coordinates". I don't believe there is a similar "collective" name for sin and cos; this is likely the furthest you can go in this direction.

Comment: @mathguy Sorry if I used the wrong terminology. I mean, if I have a right triangle, the a^2 + b^2 + c^2 kind, and I have two numbers a/c and b/c, is there a single word I can use to describe both numbers?

Comment: @DougM I looked up *normalize* just now. That sounds perfect, thank you!

Comment: Arcsin and arccos mean the angle.  The sides are simply sin and cosine.sinusoidal seems best.